# Many objects in Django admin with Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

models.py:

```
class Town(models.Model):
    ...

class People(models.Model):
    town = models.ForeignKey(Town, related_name="town")
```

But I have many towns in db, 4000-6000.

And when I use **PeopeAdmin** in **admin.py**, **Django** downloads in select-form all towns, and do this very-very slow.

How to fix that? Does I need to use **memcached** or something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields), which uses a pop-up interface rather than a select box.

Comment: nice! Thank you very much, I don't know about this!